# ResourceExhaustedError while training cnn

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, epoch

While fitting the model, with 5.5GB of .npy image processed data(converted to rgb, resized, normalized, clipped).
Total frame in the file is: 28,803

frames are resized to : (image, (227,227), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

Laptop config: 8gb ram and Nvidia Mx130

**NOTE:** while training it is observed that it runs for 2 epoch and then start to give error which takes approx 40min.

my code for training is :

```
start = datetime.now()
epochs=10
batch_size=1

callback_save = ModelCheckpoint("saved_model.h5", 
                                mode='min',
                                monitor="mean_squared_error", 
                                save_best_only=True)

callback_early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                                        verbose=1,  # we can add verbose=1 and remove epoch, wat it will do is that it will
                                                    # stop training and will stop when model stop to improve and will return
                                                    # number of epoch
                                        mode='min',
                                        patience=3)

history_1=cnn.fit(training_data,target_data, 
               validation_split=0.3,
               batch_size=batch_size, 
               epochs=epochs, 
               callbacks = [callback_save,callback_early_stopping])
cnn.save("saved_model.h5")
print("-------------------------------------------------------")
print("Total time taken for training is (HH:MM:SS): {}\n".format(datetime.now() - start))
print("-------------------------------------------------------")
print("      Training done and model is ready for testing     ")
print("-------------------------------------------------------")
```

and error is:

```
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1ab8e7e2c701> in <module>
     15                                         patience=3)
     16 
---> 17 history_1=cnn.fit(training_data,target_data, 
     18                validation_split=0.3,
     19                batch_size=batch_size,

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1841       `args` and `kwargs`.
   1842     """
-> 1843     return self._call_flat(
   1844         [t for t in nest.flatten((args, kwargs), expand_composites=True)
   1845          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1921         and executing_eagerly):
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    544         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 545           outputs = execute.execute(
    546               str(self.signature.name),
    547               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[39,260,576] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
     [[{{node gradient_tape/sequential/conv_lst_m2d_2/while/sequential/conv_lst_m2d_2/while_grad/body/_695/gradient_tape/sequential/conv_lst_m2d_2/while/gradients/sequential/conv_lst_m2d_2/while/convolution_7_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_8914]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

what would be the best practice for implementing this check.

Comment: You should get more RAM, 8 GB is just not enough.

Comment: But how much as I am not able to run it on Colab and kaggle.

Comment: Your `training_data` and `target_data`, are they the raw data or [generators](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/#generate-a-dataset)? An image size of 227x227 and `batch_size` of 1 should normally not throw an error with 8GB of RAM if loaded properly.

Comment: @Jakob Raw data and you think data is not loaded properly?

Comment: @AbhishekSrivastava That might be the case yes. You should use generators that feed the model with `batch_size` number of images in each iteration during training. If you load an entire 5.5GB dataset at once (as you seem to do now) you might have memory issues with even the largest GPUs out there. Keras makes it easy to create generators (they are also referred to Dataset objects in the documentation). Make sure to check out the link I provided above.

Comment: I also suspect you're running it on the CPU rather than the GPU as it takes so long to train one epoch before the error is thrown. Why aren't you able to run it on Colab btw? @AbhishekSrivastava